# Problem with adding a value to a key in a dictionary on python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a dictionary called counts:

```
counts = dict()
```

```py
names = ['David', 'Daniel', 'Michelle', 'Daniel', 'Ben', 'Ben', 'Daniel']
for name in names:
    if name not in names:
        counts[name] = 1
    else:
        counts[name] = counts[name] + 1
print(counts)
```

What is going wrong? I am not sure why it is not working.

Comment: change `if name not in names` to `if name not in counts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

small error, should be if name not in counts:

counts = dict()
names = ['David', 'Daniel', 'Michelle', 'Daniel', 'Ben', 'Ben', 'Daniel']
for name in names:
if name not in counts:
counts[name] = 1
else:
counts[name] = counts[name] + 1